# Solving Sturm-Liouville-equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions, sturm-liouville

> I want to solve the Sturm-Liouville-ODE
>
> $$(xy')' - x\mathrm e^{-x} y =0.$$

This equation results in when you try to simulate heat conduction with exponentially varying permeability field. Tried to fit with General bessel. Didn’t work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maple says this here $$y \left( x \right) ={\it \_C1}+\int \!{{\rm e}^{{\it Ei} \left( 1,x
 \right) }}\,{\rm d}x{\it \_C2}
$$

Comment: Note that your equation can be rewritten as $(xy')' - yx\mathrm e^{-x} = 0$, which is a Sturm-Liouville-equation.

Comment: @Jan ohh didn't notice that before. How do I move from there?

Comment: @ThreePhi I don't have a clue, but I now edited your question and added these fact.

Comment: On what interval are you working?