# Second order ODE of unknown format problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking for a Real function $R(r)$
that satisfies:

$$r^2R''+R'+m^2 rR=0$$

where $m\in\Bbb R$.

It looks a bit like an Euler DE but it isn't, and a bit like a Bessel DE but isn't either.

[Wolfram alpha (link to the ODE)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%20y%27%27%28x%29%2By%27%28x%29%2Bm%5E2%20x%20y%28x%29%3D0) doesn't recognise it and provides no solution unfortunately.

I think I need a substitution like $r=f(u)$ to get going.

Any help is appreciated.

**A little background -**

The equation is the radial equation of two ODEs obtained after separation of variables, of a heat conduction problem (a very thin disk of radius $R_1$).

*Boundary conditions are:*

$$R(R_0)=0$$
$$R'(R_1)=0$$

I upvoted the first answer because it looked like a good idea but it turned out to be incorrect, as I showed in my comment.

In response to commenter 'tomasliam', the Sturm Liouville form of the DE is:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}r}\left[e^{-1/r}R'(r)\right]+\frac{e^{-1/r}m^2R(r)}{r}=0$$

---

**On request of @themaker:**

A very thin disc of radius $R_1$ is at temperature $T_i$. It is insulated on both sides, as well as the outer edge.

At $t=0$ the area $[0,R_0]$ is suddenly heated to $T_0$.

What is the temperature evolution $T(t,r)$ of the disc (on $[R_0,R_1]$)?

Fourier heat equation for the disc, taking symmetry into account:

$$T_t=\frac{\alpha}r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\Big(r\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\Big)$$
$$\frac{T_t}{\alpha}=\frac1r(T_{r}+rT_{rr})$$
For homogeneity, we make a substitution:

$$u(t,r)=T(t,r)-T_0$$
$$\frac{u_t}{\alpha}=\frac1r(u_{r}+ru_{rr})$$
Initial:
$$u(0,r)=T_i-T_0$$
Boundaries:
$$u(t,R_0)=0$$
$$u_r(t,R_1)=0$$
Ansatz:
$$u(t,r)=\Theta (t)R(r)$$
Substitute, then divide by $u$:
$$\frac{\Theta'}{\alpha \Theta}=\frac{1}{r}\frac{R'}R+\frac{R''}R=-m^2$$
$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{R'}R+\frac{R''}R=-m^2$$
$$rR''+R'+m^2 rR=0$$
So it looks an error was made in setting up the original ODE! Mea culpa.
The solution of the last equation is:
$$R(r)=c_1J_0(mr)+c_2Y_0(mr)$$

Comment: Have you found series solutions or put it into Sturm-Louville form?

Comment: No to the first, yes to the second: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+y%27%27%28x%29%2By%27%28x%29%2Bm%5E2+x+y%28x%29%3D0

Comment: For $m=0$, [we note](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2y%27%27%28x%29%2By%27%28x%29%3D0) that solutions
$$
R(r) = c_1 \big(r e^{1/r} - \operatorname{Ei}(\tfrac1{r})\big) + c_2
$$
where $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the exponential integral are functions of $1/r$. Another hard [SL problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3296815/418542) is $(xy')' - x\mathrm e^{-x} y =0$, while it even looks simpler than yours..

Comment: Really? For $m=0$ then $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}r}\Big[e^{-1/r}R'(r)\Big]=0$, $\Rightarrow$ $e^{-1/r}R'(r)=c_1$

Comment: Yes, the same result is obtained. But I'm really looking for the eigenvalues $m$...

Comment: Is $R_0 = 0$ or positive?

Comment: Normally I'd say positive but in the limit we could say $R_0=0$. Does that help?

Comment: Yes it does. I'm fairly certain that the problem is strongly singular at $R_0 = 0$. It is definitely not solvable numerically for $R_0 = 0$, but I suspect it might even be infinite analytically

Comment: @Gert Do you mind sharing the original conduction problem?

Comment: @themaker Hi. I'll include it in the question, later on today.

Comment: How you got $R(r)=c_1J_0(mr)+c_2Y_0(mr)$ or where can I found it? Thank you

Comment: @DanielD.https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+y%27%27%28x%29%2By%27%28x%29%2Bm%5E2+x+y%28x%29%3D0

Answer (score 1):

**HINT.**

My attempts to get exact solution have not bring useful results.

At the same time, looks possible to get solution of the Sturm-Liouville equation in the series form.

Let 
$$E = e^{-{^1/_{\large r}}},\quad F=m^2ER',\quad v=\dfrac1{m^2},\tag1$$
then
$$rF' + ER = 0.\tag2$$
Denote
$$G_0(r) = \dfrac1rF',\quad G_{n+1} = r^2(G_n\!\!'+vF),\tag3$$
then
\begin{align}
&G_0 = rF' = - ER,\\
&G_0\!\!'= - E\left(R'+\dfrac1{r^2}R \right) =-vF-\dfrac1{r^2}ER,\quad
G_1\!\! = r^2(G_0\!\!'+vF) = -ER,\\
&G_1\!\!'= - E\left(R'+\dfrac1{r^2}R \right) =-vF-\dfrac1{r^2}ER,\quad
G_2\!\! = r^2(G_1\!\!'+vF) = -ER,\dots\\
&G_n = -ER,\quad n= 0,1,\dots.\tag4
\end{align}

Assuming
$$R(\rho_0) = 0,\quad R'(\rho_0) = q,\quad 
vF(\rho_0)=qe^{-{^{\large1\!}/{ \rho^\,_0}}},\quad R'(\rho_1)=0,\tag5$$
one can get
\begin{align}
&G_0\!\!'(\rho_0) = rF'(\rho_0) = 0,\quad F'(\rho_0) = 0,\tag{6.1}\\[4pt]
&G_1\!\!' = r^2\big((rF')'+vF\big) = r^3F''+r^2F'+vr^2F,\\[4pt]
&G_1\!\!'(\rho_0) = \rho_0^3F''(\rho_0)+\rho_0^2 qe^{-{^{\large1\!}/{ \rho^\,_0}}}= 0,\\[4pt]
&F''(\rho_0) = -\dfrac q{\rho_0}\,e^{-{^{\large1\!}/{ \rho^\,_0}}},\tag{6.2}\\[4pt]
&G_2\!\!' = r^2\big((r^3F''+r^2F'+vr^2F)'+vF\big)\\[4pt]
&= r^5F'''+4r^4F''+r^2(2r+v)F'+r^2(2r+1)vF,\\[4pt]
&G_2\!\!'(\rho_0) = \rho_0^5F'''(\rho_0)+\rho_0^2(1-2\rho_0)
qe^{-{^{\large1\!}/{ \rho^\,_0}}}= 0,\\[4pt]
&F'''(\rho_0) = \dfrac {2\rho_0-1}{\rho_0^3}\,qe^{-{^{\large1\!}/{ \rho^\,_0}}},\dots\tag{6.3}\\[4pt]
\end{align}

This recurrent process should obtain Taylor series for $F(r)$ and then for $R(r).$

Possible problem is applying of the condition to the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

If we take $R=e^{f(r)}$ we get:
$$e^{f(r)}(r^2f’’(r)+2f’(r)+m^2r)$$
After a little algebraic manipulation and use of $e^{f(r)}$ never equaling 0:
$$r^2f’’(x)+2f’(r)=-m^2r$$
By integrating and use of integration by parts you might be able to solve it from there.

Comment: Sadly there's an error in your derivations, because: $R''=e^{f(r)}[f''(r)+f'(r)^2]$. So the ODE becomes second degree.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to contribute a numerical solution to your equation. I have the derivation of the numerical procedure and python code in jupyter. I can share both if there is interest.

I have performed finite difference discretization of the equation. I have assumed

- $n = 1000$ - the number of discretization points
- $r_0 = 1$ - the inner edge of the disc
- $r_n = 5$ - the outer edge of the disc

Note it is not possible to naively place the inner edge at zero because of singularity.

Using finite differences I have converted the problem into a linear discrete eigenvalue problem for a 3-diagonal matrix.

[image: Eigenvalue Plot]

Here is a plot of sorted eigenvalues $m$ (not $m^2$) by index for progressively improving discretization. It is not unreasonable to hypothesize that the in continuum limit the eigenvalues are a linear function of their index.

[image: Evec1]
[image: Evec2]
[image: Evec3]
These are the first three eigenvectors. As expected, the following eigenvectors continue oscillating more and more.

Comment: Thank you for your work. Are these eigenvectors obtained for $n=1000$?

Comment: Yes, the eigenvectors are for the case $n=1000$. For $n=500$ the first few look quite simular

Comment: So what are the numerical values of the first $3$ eigenvalues?

Comment: Here are first 10 :)
[0.45607236, 1.33735621, 2.23632993, 3.13494659, 4.03305012, 4.930833, 5.82841248, 6.72585358, 7.62319328, 8.52045335]

Comment: You seem to show very high confidence levels [$7$ sign. digits and better]. Is that justified?

Comment: Probably not. Python uses double precision floating point numbers by default. I did not study how precise the eigenvalues actually are. As seen from the plot, the eigenvalue curves seem to converge with improving discretization. I would expect the smaller eigenvalues to be more precise than the larger ones

Comment: OK. I'll leave the question open for a little longer because an analytical solution would still be preferred. If no one comes up with one, I'll award your answer with the bounty. I think your solution is workable for what I have in mind.

Comment: Feel free to ask follow-up questions, I'm also happy to give you the code so you can modify it to your precise problem. I was hoping that the numerical solution would help others figure out the potential analytical solution. But, truth be told, for nonlinear equations chances are typically slim...

Comment: Again thank you for your work.